# alpha in sklearn LogisticRegression python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

What is the default alpha in sklearn LogisticRegression with l1 penalty?

```
lmMod = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html),

The parameter used for the the regularization is the parameter `C` in the input of the call. I represents the inverse of regularization strength. The default value is equal to 1.

> C : float, default: 1.0 Inverse of regularization strength; must be a
>   positive float. Like in support vector machines, smaller values
>   specify stronger regularization.